# A Remote GUI for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, linux, ubuntu, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I've installed PostgreSQL 12 server onto an Ubuntu 20.04 server, but I want to access it using a GUI from my Kubuntu 20.04 laptop. I'd be interested to know any options for GUI administration.

I have an old Access database that I used mdbtools to export all tables to csv files. I'm wanting to import those table into PostgreSQL, but I'd really like something nicer than the command line.

One option I know about is pgadmin, however, it isn't clear to me where I should install that. Do I install it on the server or my laptop? I see that it is a web interface, I don't want to run a web server on my laptop just to have a GUI for Postgres located on a server. I'd like some direction from someone who uses a GUI to administer PostgreSQL remotely.

I've used Access, DB2, SQL Server, MySQL, MarinaDB, and Pervasive, but this is my first time messing with Postgres. Hopefully, I've saved the best for last. Please advise.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients

Comment: you can install pgAdmin [in server mode](https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#2). Alternatively you can use OmniDB

Answer (score 1):

Use pgadmin (Open source)
https://www.pgadmin.org/

It has the same comofort as phpmyadmin, mysql  workbench ssms, and with some kings.

Answer (score -2):

Workbench can connect to Postgres Server

Ref :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-postgresql-drivers-linux.html

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/postgresql-workbench

https://data36.com/install-sql-workbench-postgresql/

Table Data Export and Import Wizard is available in Workbench using csv

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html

Comment: MySQL Workbench doesn't work with Postgres

Comment: Please follow this https://phoenixnap.com/kb/postgresql-workbench

Comment: That link refers to SQL Workbench/J which is somehting completely different than MySQL Workbench